# How can I make a foreign-key case-insensitive in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, mariadb, foreign-key, migration, case-sensitive

I have a Mariab-database using collation utf8bm4_general_ci and I am migrating to Postgresql.

Some tables are foreign keyed using case-insensitive strings (e-mails sourced from different systems).

When I use [pgloader](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader) to migrate, I get an error message stating that some keys are not present. I can update the source table to be able to do the migration, but the error will present itself after a while if I do the switch.

What can I do to fix this other than rewriting and debugging all systems to make sure e-mails are lowercased?

Comment: [Collation Support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/collation.html)

Comment: Thank you, i have read about it and an option is to create a non-deterministic collation. The downside is that it breaks queries with 'LIKE'. An option is to cast the relevant columns to CITEXT but i cannot find out how to do this for columns with specific names.

Comment: You may specify the collation in the expression, like `WHERE column = 'literal' COLLATE "collation"`